# Are Chrome bookmarks used by Google Search to improve their search results?

Tags: google-search

I am wondering if Google uses the data from all Google Chrome users for their weighting of search results. A simple bookmark count would reveal importance, then they could prioritize the search results accordingly.

I only found [here](https://backlinko.com/google-ranking-factors) the short info:

> 134. Chrome Bookmarks: We know that Google collects Chrome browser usage data. Pages that get bookmarked in Chrome might get a boost.

But no more details on that topic.

Is Google using the data? And if yes, to what extent?

Comment: That's a good question, but I doubt you'll get an authoritative answer from anyone outside of Google.

Comment: I doubt it. If it were true it would be too easy to game.